# What exactly is the role of TestEnv class?

Tags: flow-project

I am trying to run the stabilizing_highway.py script in /examples/rllib folder and have collected a set of learning checkpoints. Now I want to compare the improvement due to learning with a baseline scenario like what would have happened if there was no autonomous agents.

I recently came across a TestEnv class. If I just replace the current WaveAttenuationMergePOEnv env_name with TestEnv in the same code, will it simulate the very normal human driving behavior in exact same configuration with no learning ?

Will this be a good replica to be considered as a baseline ?

Answer (score 0):

as your question is from some while ago, you probably found the answer for yourself but I still try to answer this for other people that have this question:
The TestEnv class is used to do simulation without any goal of training. Therefore it computes a zero reward, and defines empty action- and observation-spaces.
As far as I understood its purpose is exactly what you ask for.

BR, Vallout